# How can I provide a supplement to an existing Logback configuration?

Tags: java, configuration, logback, slf4j

I need to provide a drop-in solution for obfuscating certain patterns that occur in log output. The idea is that I can provide either a supplemental config file or a configuration class that will modify the existing Logback configuration to start utilizing my obfuscation logic.

Currently, I have a logback.xml file configured with an implementation of the [MessageConverter](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/pattern/MessageConverter.html) class that's doing all of the obfuscation work that I need but only for the dummy project that these files exist in.

Ideally, I'd like to turn this dummy project into a library that I could add as a dependency to a new project and the new project would inherit the log obfuscation behavior.

I came across [this part of the configuration docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#fileInclusion) that allows including the contents of one configuration file in another but it requires a special tag exist in both files. This wouldn't work unless I manually modified the existing configuration files for every project I want to apply this to.